# Flutter - widgets don't align correctly in row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I place the **HOME** widget in the left side of each green box and the **SEARCH ICON** on the right.

[image]

I tried using `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,`But only pushing it to the middle of the container.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Habits extends StatelessWidget {
  const Habits({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green[200],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
            Text('Home'),
            Icon(Icons.search),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the parent class of `Habits`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly you want. If you want HOME on the left corner and ICON on the right corner, you can delete this line:

```
Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
```

Comment: removing padding does work but removes the styling. I want Home to be on far left(not in the middle) and an search icon on far right

Comment: What kind of style does padding add?

Answer (score 0):

remove the padding inside the row widget and warp your row widget with the padding

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0),
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.green[200],
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
    ),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text('Home'),
          Icon(Icons.search),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the Home Widget on the left and the icon on the right you have several options

1- Use the [Listtile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) widget. It is flexible and already has all the settings you need.

```dart
    Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green[200],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              child: ListTile(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                title: const Text('Home'),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

2- Use your approach and wrap the Home widget in an [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget.

```dart
    Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green[200],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                      child: Text('Home'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
```

If you are a new flutter developer, I suggest you give yourself 15 minutes every day to the [flutter widget of the week](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdkRy3yZiPo&list=PLjxrf2q8roU23XGwz3Km7sQZFTdB996iG) channel.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a spacer to push both widgets to the furthest extremes.

```
Row(
        children: [
          Text('Home'),
          Spacer(),
          Icon(Icons.search),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: it push both the HOME & SEARCH ICONS to the right corner. I want Home to be on far left and an search icon on far right

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Please see the edit @A-Commons